# How can I create a vector of subsets in Pari/GP?

Tags: pari-gp

I want to produce a vector containing all *k*-element subsets of a second vector. I know that I can do this by **apply**ing **vecextract** with each *k*-element subset of the natural numbers 1...*n* to my original vector.

How can I create that vector of subsets of natural numbers, though? I can see that the command **forsubset** does nearly what I want, but it's an imperative command, not one which creates a vector. So I could use the following function to print a list of vectors:
`f(n,k)=forsubset([n,k],s,print(s))` but I can only capture them by adding each subset to a List() and then converting the List() to a Vec(). This seems clumsy. Is there a better way to do this, perhaps a totally different one?

Comment: Please, review my answer to the similar SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33488332/is-there-a-comfortable-way-to-generate-the-combinations-k-out-of-n-in-pari-gp/33495106#33495106

Comment: That does seem to answer it well. Thanks!